# Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to figure out how to translate this in Swift and I am also having this error: "Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments".  Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

```
var pageImages:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()
pageImages = [UIImage(named: "example.png"), UIImage(named: "example2.png")]
```

Comment: Assuming both images exist, your code works fine for me. Are you sure the problem is with these two lines?

Comment: @DanielT. Then you are not using Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1). His code does not compile.

Answer (score 14):

Confirming what matt says:

in xCode 6.0 this does work:

```
images = [UIImage(named: "steps_normal"), UIImage(named: "steps_big")]
```

but in xCode6.1 values should be unwrapped:

```
images = [UIImage(named: "steps_normal")!, UIImage(named: "steps_big")!]
```

Comment: or, maybe, even better

`images = [UIImage(named: "steps_normal") ?? UIImage(), UIImage(named: "steps_big") ?? UIImage()]`
so in case if no image found - app will not crash

Answer (score 3):

Unwrap those optionals. A UIImage is not the same as a UIImage?, which is what the `named:` initializer returns. Thus:

```
var pageImages = [UIImage(named: "example.png")!, UIImage(named: "example2.png")!]
```

(Unless, of course, you actually *want* an array of optional UIImages.)

Comment: Actually, according to the Xcode 6.0 documentation, it returns a UIImage, but you are right that such a return doesn't make sense. I think it actually returns an implicitly unwrapped conditional.

Comment: But he is using Xcode 6.1 (released yesterday, and available in beta for some time previously). I guarantee it, because I recognize the error message he's getting. If he weren't using 6.1, his code would compile and we wouldn't be here. `init(named:)` now (correctly) returns an optional. It is not implicitly unwrapped. That is why he must unwrap it.

Comment: It looks like I have some more updating to do. Glad to hear they are making the library better.

Comment: @DanielT. They made it worse first, so be very glad that you missed the first couple of 6.1 betas. Horrible.

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage(named:)` changed to be a *failable initializer* in Xcode 6.1, which means that it will return `nil` if any of the images you've listed are missing from your bundle. To safely load the images, try something like this instead:

```
var pageImages = [UIImage]()
for name in ["example.png", "example2.png"] {
    if let image = UIImage(named: name) {
        pageImages.append(image)
    }
}
```