# Could Not Find Overload for 'Init' - UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode and now I'm getting a "Could not find an overload for 'Init' that accepts the supplied argument" error.  The line that's causing this error is:

```
leftDigitImage.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "blink_anim.gif"),UIImage(named: "empty led.png")]
```

leftDigitImage is an outlet that's defined as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftDigitImage: UIImageView!
```

It worked fine in the previous version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
leftDigitImage.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "blink_anim.gif")!, UIImage(named: "empty led.png")!]
```

The problem is that UIImage `init(named:)` now returns an optional, so you need to unwrap them.

Comment: This code will crash your app if one of those images is renamed or missing - see this answer for how to safely create those images: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26511613/59541

Comment: @NateCook That is true, but I think we can safely assume that none of the images is renamed or missing. Besides, when I'm in this situation, I _want_ to crash if I've gotten the name wrong.

Comment: I just don't think we should be offering `!` so quickly as a solution - it tends to creep in unsafe places if used without reservations.

Comment: @NateCook Fine. But I don't think the fact that our _philosophies_ differ is sufficient justification for your downvoting me. What I said here and elsewhere isn't _wrong_ — and you know it. I allow you your view; allow me mine, please.