# How to animate images in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have updated to last version of xcode with ios 8.1 sdk and I get an error ion declaration of my function in:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var imageAnimation: UIImageView!

  imageAnimation.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: "5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "4.png"),
        UIImage(named: "3.png"),
        UIImage(named: "2.png"),
        UIImage(named: "1.png")
    ]
```

The error is: 'Type UIImage? does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

How can animate images?

Thanks!

Comment: Not again!!! Do you see the trailing question mark `UIImage?` in the error message? That indicates an *optional* which has to be unwrapped ...

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442059/could-not-find-an-overload-for-init-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments-in-swi

Comment: will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511448/could-not-find-overload-for-init-uiimage

Answer (score 8):

Small code example for you. Use array and for loop to do this.

```
    //add images to the array
    var imagesListArray :NSMutableArray = []
    //use for loop
    for position in 1...5
    {

        var strImageName : String = "c\(position).png"
        var image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
        imagesListArray.addObject(image)
    }

    self.imageView.animationImages = imagesListArray;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: You Cannot assign value of type ```NSMutableArray``` to type ```[UIImage]?```. Change to :```var imgListArray : [UIImage?] = []``` and ```UIImage(named:strImageName)!``` and ```imgListArray.append(image)```